# Oracle JDBC Diagnostics with JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: sql, oracle, jboss

How can I log sql in JBoss EAP 6.1. I'm using Oracle.

Link to resource: Oracle JDBC Diagnostics [http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm#CIAIEEFF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359%5f01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm#CIAIEEFF)

I'm using ojdbc6_g JDBC driver.

```
myJdbcLoggingConfig.properties:

.level=CONFIG
oracle.jdbc.level=CONFIG
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=CONFIG
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=C:/work/jdbc.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Java VM Parameters in Jboss-Tools (Eclipse):

```
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/work/myJdbcLoggingConfig.properties
```

But I did not get any results. What can be wrong with my configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use a jboss 7 standard for jdbc logging like this:

http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1050

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I'm using this solution now. Your reply doesn't exactly answer the question but it is useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I have done in JBoss 7.1.1 to get the debugging version of the Oracle driver to log:

1. Replaced the ojdbc6.jar file with the ojdbc6_g.jar file at $JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc/main. I replaced the JAR there with the "_g" but kept the name, so I didn't have to change any other config files.
2. Added the "-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true" statement to the JAVA_OPTS in my JBoss startup script.
3. Most importantly, I added logging categories for the Oracle JDBC debugging to my standalone.xml :

-Inside the

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
```

section I added a separate file logger for the Oracle stuff. You don't have to do this but the server log is already pretty cluttered.  You do this by defining a file logger:

```
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="JDBCLOG">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="networkpacket.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Name it whatever you want; I chose "networkpacket.log"

-Create the log categories for the Oracle logging information. Note they use different levels that log4j ():

```
        <logger category="oracle.jdbc" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="CONFIG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="JDBCLOG"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
        <logger category="oracle.net.ns" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="CONFIG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="JDBCLOG"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

You can create log categories for all of the different pieces the Oracle debugging logger documentation defines, just make sure you use the right logging levels:

- OFF
- SEVERE
- WARNING
- INFO
- CONFIG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST

The benefit now is that you can use the `jboss-cli` command line tool to on-the-fly change the levels.

Comment: Hey, thank you. I have not tried your advice yet. Your solution looks good.

Comment: Particularly useful is the hint to the *_g.jar (which is part of the "Diagnosability related JARs").